# Mocking react-redux 8 reducer functions in tests using JEST and RTL

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a react application with react-redux 7 written about 2 years ago. I wanted to update various third party libraries to the latest version and I run into an issue with migrating to react-redux 8.
When I used the old, redux 7 scheme of using "connect", mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToPros functions, I was able to mock individual reducer functions like this:

```
const activateMock= jest.fn();

describe('AccountActivation', () => {
    it('Should call activation endpoint after entering the page', () => {
        render(
            <Router>
                <AccountActivation activate={activateMock}
                    isAuthenticated={false} loading={false}
                    {...routeComponentPropsMock} />
            </Router>);

        expect(activateMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
})
```

All the state variables and action dispatching methods were easy. However, with react-redux 8, I had to significantly refactor all my code to start using useAppDispatch and useAppSelector hooks, as described in the documentation. I went through [the page about testing](https://redux.js.org/usage/writing-tests), and tried to refactor my tests as described - using renderWithProviders function and passing preloadedState:

```
const activateMock= jest.fn();

describe('AccountActivation', () => {
    it('Should call activation endpoint after entering the page', () => {
        renderWithProviders(
            <Router>
                <EmployeeAccountActivation />
            </Router>, {
            preloadedState: {
                account: {
                    isAuthenticated: false,
                    loading: false
            }
        });

        expect(activateMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
})
```

but how can I mock the reducer function so that I can assert that it was called?

I tried mocking just this single function from the reducer like this:

```
const activateMock= jest.fn();
jest.mock('../account-reducer', () => ({
    ...jest.requireActual('../account-reducer'),
    activate: () => activateMock
}));
```

But when I do this, I get an error that "account" reducer passed in preloadedState does not exist:

> Unexpected key "account" found in preloadedState argument passed to createStore.

How can I mock this activate method from the reducer? I know that redux documentation encourages to change the approach from component oriented tests to integration tests that check the entire flow, including reducer methods, by using a mock HTTP server. However, the amount of work required to do that for my suite of 557 test cases is simply to large to do that on top of all the other refactoring I'm doing.

The only alternative solution that I found so far is mocking the the useDispatch hook from react-redux but I'm not sure how I can check that the correct function was dispatched with the correct arguments.

Here's the implementation of my renderWithProviders method:

```
interface ExtendedRenderOptions extends Omit<RenderOptions, 'queries'> {
  preloadedState?: PreloadedState<IRootState>
  store?: any
}

export function renderWithProviders(
  ui: React.ReactElement,
  {
    preloadedState = {},
    // Automatically create a store instance if no store was passed in
    store = getStore(preloadedState),
    ...renderOptions
  }: ExtendedRenderOptions = {}
) {
  function Wrapper({ children }: PropsWithChildren<{}>): JSX.Element {
    return <Provider store={store}>{children}</Provider>
  }

  // Return an object with the store and all of RTL's query functions
  return { store, ...render(ui, { wrapper: Wrapper, ...renderOptions }) }
}
```

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated.